# Aligning text centre of image below bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish too have text directly below my images so I tried the following but it did not work. I want the text direclty below and to the centre of the picture

```
<div class="our_partners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $image1, 'full' )); ?>" alt=""></a>
                           <span>High Speed Wifi</span> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $image2, 'full' )); ?>" alt=""></a>
                          <span>    Latest Av Technology</span>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $image3, 'full' )); ?>" alt=""></a>
                          <span>            Online Booking</span>


                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $image4, 'full' )); ?>" alt=""></a>
  <span>            Concierge Service</span>


                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url( $image5, 'full' )); ?>" alt=""></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can see the result here

[image]

and you can see it live here if you scroll down to services

http://ubtanz.solitudesoftware.co.uk/

Comment: If your question was answered, you should mark one of the answers, to assist others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give img

```
.our_partners ul li a img {
    padding: 29px 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Remove margin-right: 15px; to margin-right: 0;

```
.our_partners ul li a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

to li

```
.our_partners ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

and

```
span {

        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.our_partners ul li a {
    margin: auto;
}

.our_partners ul li a img {
    padding: 10px 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.our_partners ul li a {
    width:230px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Throw this in your custom.css - makes it centered.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text inside the `<a></a>` tag, like so:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><img src="...s2-3.png" alt="">
        <span style="display:block;">High Speed Wifi</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**EDIT** To ensure that all images are aligned, you can set the last image up as:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><img src="...cons-2.png" alt="">
        <span style="display:block;">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Further, you can obviously set a style on the `<span>` element in your css file, to cut down on repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `margin-right: 15px` property on the list element, and not the `anchor` element because it makes more sense. You are separating between the list elements and not the anchors.

With that change in mind, all you need to do now is set the `span` element to take 100% of the available width, and center align its content.

```
.our_partners li {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.our_partners a li span {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and remove your current margin set from the `anchor` element:

```
.our_partners ul li a {
    margin-right: 15px;    // <- remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, use `<br/>`:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="..." alt=""></a><br/>
    <span>High Speed Wifi</span>
  </li>
  (...)
```

A better way, threat one of the part as a block, by default, `a` `img` and `span` tags are inline:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" style="display:block;"><img src="..." alt=""></a>
    <span>High Speed Wifi</span>
  </li>
  (...)
```

Externalize the css style in a class. You could even wrap the linked image into a block span:

```
# foo.css:
span.span-block { display: block; }
...
# 42.html
<span class="span-block"><a ...><img .../></a></span>
...
```